# Is it thread-safe to Send and Receive on the same Python Socket simultaneously?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am developing a multi-threaded server in Python for a project (where I am required to use the raw sockets, not other libraries), but I could not find any clear answer online as to whether or not it is safe to send and receive on a Python TCP Socket simultaneously from different threads.

I did find that sockets are not thread-safe with regards to sending from multiple threads, or receiving from multiple threads, but I was unable to find whether it's safe to have a single thread receiving and a single thread sending on the same socket.

Is there any documentation that clearly answers this question, or if not, does anyone know whether or not this is safe to do without requiring any additional concurrency control?